# Drupal 10, /sites/default/files css and js folders/files missing

Tags: drupal, drupal-10

I just installed Drupal 10. /sites/default/files/js & /sites/default/files/css/ are missing. I'm running development environment on macOS.

I've checked http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/reports/status and there are no error showing.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Those folders are created when javascript and css aggregation is turned on (it's where the generated files are stored by default).
Just turn that setting on, it is on the performance admin page.

You can change where these generated css and js files are stored with [settings['file_assets_path']](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.1.6/sites/default/default.settings.php?ref_type=tags#L491)

Answer (score 0):

I received the same problem.
AdvAgg doesn't have yet a stable version for Drupal 10 and is not installed, but the option is set on.

***Note:*** AdvAgg needs a major rework for Drupal 10.1; I  recommend holding off on updating, or otherwise disabling AdvAgg until a new release comes out.

So you can install an Alpha version, or just turn that setting off—it is on the Performance Admin page.